# Problem In Displaying the filtered data In Yajara Data Table

Tags: laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

I am Using Laravel Yajara Data Table Package I was able to send the Ajax request to my controller with the following code

```
<script>
```

function getDataAsPerDate() {

var selected_date = document.getElementById("date").value;

```
alert(selected_date);
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: "{{route('package.getDateData')}}",
    data:{selected_date:selected_date},
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#msg").html(data.msg);
    }
});
```

}

And The controller Code `

```
public function getDateData(Request $request){
    $selected_date=$request->selected_date;
    $getPackageDetail=packages::whereDate('date',$selected_date)->get();
    return response()->json($getPackageDetail); 
    }
```

`
The response looks something like this [image: Ajax Response]

I just wanna show this Response in my datatable